# Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection when running `knex migrate`

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm running `./node_modules/.bin/knex migrate:latest --env local`

Which results in the following error:

```
> knex migrate:latest --env local

Requiring external module ts-node/register
Using environment: local
TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
at /Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:318:17
    at tryCatcher (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at /Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/catch_filter.js:17:41
    at tryCatcher (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/ashok/src/super-abs/alpha/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

I've even tried deleting the database and re-running.

Are there connections I need to clear somehow? My app is not running.

Using the following

`"knex": "0.19.0",`

node -v: `v14.0.0`

`psql (PostgreSQL) 11.7`

Comment: I've also run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres restart` to restart postgres. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3831 Upgrading node-pg to 8 could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by simply downgrading to node version 13.11.0:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 13.11.0
knex migrate:latest
#  Requiring external module ts-node/register
#  Using environment: local
#  Batch 1 run: 63 migrations
```

Yay.

Answer (score 1):

```
Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full...
```

upgrading pg@8.3.0 resolved the problem.
Environment:
node 14.6
pg:7.8
"knex": "^0.20.10",

> https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3912
> https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3912#issuecomment-657715661